# The kanji for "YOMI": Word For "Reading the Mind of Your Opponent"

Tags: words, kanji

"Yomi" is a Japanese concept used by game theorists and high-level, fighting game players. I came across it in February 2019 in a novel and it is quite hard to find information about it online. All I need is the kanji though...

Comment: 読み is a perfectly ordinary word meaning 'reading'. It's not a uniquely Japanese concept *at all*. *Most* competitive action games are about reading your opponent's moves and reacting to them.

Comment: Have you tried any English→Japanese dictionaries?

Comment: Not that hard to find information... :http://game.fantasystrike.com/forums/index.php?threads/quick-question-about-the-original-japanese-word-yomi.10088/

Comment: Sorry, only tried jisho.org for dictionaries. Thanks for the answer. It is a bit embarrassing that I didn't make the connection, but all the content I found suggested a whole level of depth to the concept. As a strong chess and go player, I am very familiar with "reading". @Aeon, I would suggest posting your comment as the answer, unless everyone thinks the question should be deleted.

Comment: Just for your own verification, here is a dictionary entry confirming that definition: https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%83%A8%E3%83%9F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you're looking for is 読み, which is an extremely basic word that means "reading". The verb itself is something you may want to learn on the first day of learning Japanese, but 読み is a conjugated form. Its "dictionary form" is [読む](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%AA%AD%E3%82%80).

In gaming contexts, 読み also means predicting or guessing what will happen in the near future. ("Reading the opponent's mind" seems a little too specific to me because 読み can be a purely logical process. For example a recent computer chess program can do 読み better than human beings.) It's critically important in card games and board games like chess, but of course action game players have to do some 読み, too.